# Show/hide multiple elements with JQUERY/HTML when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is what I have so far:

```
<div style="position: relative;"> <a href="#games">
    <div class="sidenavOff">
    <img src = "images/card_normal.png" />
    <img src = "images/category_icons/icon_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;" />
    <img src = "images/category_titles/title_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 40px;" />
    </div>
    <div class = "sidenavOver">
    <img src = "images/hover/card_hover.png" />
    <img src = "images/category_titles/title_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;" />
    <img src = "images/hover/card_hover_separator.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px;" />
    Show a bunch of text here
    <img src = "images/button_start_normal.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 40px;" />
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

So card.png is a notecard that has multiple transparent images overlayed on top of it. When the mouse is away from the card, it has icon_games.png and title_games.png showing on the card. I want it so that when the mouse hovers over card.png, icon_games.png, or title_games.png (in other words, whenever the mouse pointer is in the card), the card displays the elements title_games.png, card_hover_separator.png, a text description, and button_start_normal.png, in that order vertically (and the positioning of this should be editable as it will likely be different than the images displayed when not hovering).

This is my jquery code (I've never used it before so I'm pretty sure this is off. I don't quite understand it):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(“div.sidenavOff”).mouseover(function () {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(“sidenavOver”);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(“sidenavOff”);
    });
});
```

In a more understandable format, without hover:

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/7026/screenshot20130606at122.png

With hover:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/screenshot20130606at122.png/

Comment: `.removeClass()` needs to know what to remove, eg. `.removeClass('sidenavOff')`

Comment: you could just do all this using `a .sideNavOff` and `a:hover sidenavOver` class and without involving any jquery

Comment: @Orbling - no it doesn't !

Comment: @jammykam can you explain/show me further? This is my first time using HTML/JQUERY/CSS and I'm a bit confused at how it works. Should mention I never defined sidenavOff and sidenavOver in my css class either (thought I could just name it like you can name an id)

Comment: @adeneo Didn't realise the parameter was optional.  I've never had a use-case where I wanted to remove all classes from anything, sounds unsafe and fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="parent" style="position: relative;"> 
    <a href="#games">
        <div class="sidenavOff">
            <img src = "images/card_normal.png" />
            <img src = "images/category_icons/icon_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;" />
            <img src = "images/category_titles/title_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 40px;" />
        </div>
        <div class = "sidenavOver">
            <img src = "images/hover/card_hover.png" />
            <img src = "images/category_titles/title_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;" />
            <img src = "images/hover/card_hover_separator.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px;" />
                 Show a bunch of text here
            <img src = "images/button_start_normal.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 40px;" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent .sidenavOver {display:none;}

.parent:hover .sidenavOver {display:block;}
.parent:hover .sidenavOff  {display:none;}
```

There's no need for javascript for this ?

Comment: As long as an element is inside another element, using the css `:hover` method will work the same way, and to just change simple CSS rules, that is far easier than using jQuery.

Comment: do you possibly know how to make it fade in and out?

Comment: @user2457563 - with CSS3 or jQuery ?

Answer (score 2):

As i said, you don't need JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/arEQy/

```
.sidenavOver {display:none}
a:hover .sidenavOff {display:none}
a:hover .sidenavOver {display:block}
```

You should add in some class names for the parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show a different when you mouse over the 'off' variation. And when you leave the 'Over' variation you want to show the original.  This can be accomplished with this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.sidenavOff").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".sidenavOver").show();
        $(this).hide();
    })

    $("div.sidenavOver").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".sidenavOff").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing changed :/ I put this in my header: <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(“div.sidenavOff”).mouseover(function () {
        $(".sidenavOver").show();
        $(".sidenavOff").hide();
    })

    $(“div.sidenavOver”).mouseout(function () {
        $(".sidenavOff").show();
        $(".sidenavOver").hide();
    });
});
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically use CSS and the hover pseudo-class to achieve your ends:

```
.sidenavOver:hover {
    display:none
}
```

This would have the unfortunate side effect of flashing when you move your cursor, though, since :hover doesn't work when an element is hidden or not displayed.

The best option is Michael_B's answer, which takes advantage of jQuery's nifty helper functions [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
.

Comment: Or you could just use the hover state of the parent element. jQuery show/hide just adds `display:block`/`display:none` and so any flashes of elements would be same anyway